# Interactive PDF to management of reports

Tags: pdf, database, pdf-generation

I am looking for some solution for management of reports. Is it possible to create interactive PDF with functions like:

- add images
- add attachments like images, emails, files etc.
- sending information to database like date.

The template file may be created in Adobe InDesign, but users have access only to Adobe Reader. Is it possible? Or what solution should I use? I need something to get me the possibility to create reports with text, images, date, attachments like emails, files etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/indesign/using/dynamic-pdf-documents.html), Indesign cannot create PDFs with this functionality. Forms in Acrobat (see [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/acrobat/using/collecting-pdf-form-data.html)) will let you add fields to a form that will allow the user to images and dates, but not arbitary files. These forms also have certain functionalaity for clicking a button to upload a PDF, as well as collecting responses from returned PDFs. It seems your use case requires a more advanced solution, such as a web-based solution such as [Google Forms](https://www.google.co.uk/forms/about/).